# Scroll to the top by second tapped to Bar Item

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I need to scroll to the top when I tapped second time to the first `BarButtonItem` (Home). There are a lot of answers  but none of them don't work for me. It's incredible but it is. 
I have `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in my class, `self.tabBarController?.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad()` and this in my `TableViewController`:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 0 {
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -60), animated: true)
        }
    }
```

It works everytime I tapped to the Home (index = 0), but I need to do this when I'm already on the Home screen (standart function for all social media to scroll to the top Feed by tapping `Home`). And how to set Y coordinate if I have a `NavigationBar` above?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is check if selected viewController is your view controller that has tableView you need to scroll to top. Now I'd recommend using scroll to instead of setting content offset because that may vary based on the device and other logic (like large title for example)

Considering you have your custom tab bar controller that has all the tabs references you could do something like this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if viewController == myViewController {
            myViewController.tableView.scrollToRow(
                           at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0),
                           at: .top,
                           animated: true)
          }
        }
    }
```